# Php Redirect ID To Another File Fom ID

Tags: php, redirect

Hi everyone I have Php CMS with some broked functions.I have menu and have 6 items on this menu.

```
home.php?id=1      =>>  home.php
home.php?id=2      =>>  about-us.php
home.php?id=3      =>>  products.php
home.php?id=4      =>>  referances.php
home.php?id=5      =>>  gallery.php
home.php?id=6      =>>  contact.php
```

like this.When i click any of them on menu url is showing their ids but not redirecet to file.I want to do when ID is 1 redirect home.php
when id is 2 redirect about-us.php when id is 3 redirect products.php and others.I'm new on php what will i have to do for this

Comment: Can you show your current code that isn't working? Are you trying to do "pretty urls"?

Comment: This approach will lead to bad SEO

Answer (score 1):

[Use `$_GET` to retrieve the "id" variable:](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

```
$num = (isset($_GET["id"] ? intval($_GET["id"]) : 1);
```

[Then use a `switch/case` to decide how to handle the variable:](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

```
switch($num){

    case 1:
        header("location: home.php"); exit;
        break;

    case 2:
        header("location: about-us.php"); exit;
        break;

    //... etc ...

    default:
        header("location: home.php"); exit;
        break;
}
```